# AWS Lambda SNS event is not binding to the correct SNS Topic ARN using Serverless yml

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, serverless-framework

I have a serverless resource for SNS topic in the resources section  in the serverless.yml something like this,

```
resources:
  Resources:
    SNSTopic:
      Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
      Properties:
        DisplayName: SNS Topic
        TopicName: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-Topic
```

When I am trying to bind this SNS topic to my lambda event as given below, lambda is not triggering by the SNS event. When I check AWS console for that lambda function the SNS event bound with wrong ARN value.

```
Function:
    handler: src/sample/file.lambdaHandler
    role: s3FullAccessRole
    events: SNSTopic
    Properties:
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaExecute
        - Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
```

I have tried with changing event with all the different ways mentioned in here, https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/sns/. The only way I found is to hard code the SNS Topic ARN value in the lambda event, which is not ideal for my situation.
Any help is really  appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it!

I end up removing my SNS TOPIC declaration from resource section of serverless.yml added under iamRoleStatements, something like this,

```
 iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - SNS:Publish
      Resource: { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["arn:aws:sns:${self:provider.region}:", { "Ref" : "AWS::AccountId" }, ":${self:custom.mySnsTopic}" ] ]  }
```

And added variables in the custom section

```
custom:  
  mySnsTopic: "${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-sns-consume"
  mySnsTopicArn: { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["arn:aws:sns:${self:provider.region}:", { "Ref" : "AWS::AccountId" }, ":${self:custom.mySnsTopic}" ] ]  }
```

then mapped this to the lambda function events

```
Function:
    handler: src/sample/file.lambdaHandler
    role: s3FullAccessRole
    events: ${self:custom.mySnsTopicArn}
    Properties:
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaExecute
```

For reference [link](https://github.com/didil/serverless-lambda-sns-example/blob/master/serverless.yml)

Answer (score 1):

You could actually create a variable in custom with the arn of the sns topic

```
custom:
  region: ${opt:region, self:provider.region}
  snsTopic: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-Topic 
  snsTopicArn: { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["arn:aws:sns:${self:custom.region}:", { "Ref" : "AWS::AccountId" }, ":${self:custom.snsTopic}" ] ]  }
```

then just use the arn on the places you need.

Or you can use the plugin https://github.com/silvermine/serverless-plugin-external-sns-events to basic reference the topic name.

If you have only 1 serverless.yml and don't want to have a separate cloudformation file I would use the first option

EDIT:

To use the arn follow the instructions on serverless https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/sns#using-a-pre-existing-topic

```
functions:
  dispatcher:
    handler: <handler>
    events:
      - sns:
          arn: ${self:custom.snsTopicArn}
```

since you have the sns topic on the same serverless.yml, you can even ignore the `snsTopicArn` variable and build it like one of the suggestions using !Ref which should be a better option for you:

```
functions:
  dispatcher:
    handler: <handler>
    events:
      - sns:
          arn: !Ref SNSTopic
          topicName: ${self:custom.snsTopic}
```

full example:

```
service: testsns
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: eu-west-1

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - sns:
          arn: !Ref SuperTopic
          topicName: MyCustomTopic
    Properties:
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaExecute
        - Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
resources:
  Resources:
    SuperTopic:
      Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
      Properties:
        TopicName: MyCustomTopic
```

Comment: Tried first option, replaced event value with "events: -sns: ${self:custom.snsTopicArn}" got this error on serverless deploy "Missing or invalid topicName property for sns event in function "Function" The correct syntax is: sns: topic-name-or-arn OR an object with arn and topicName OR topicName and displayName. Please check the docs for more info"

Comment: Tried this too, "events: - sns: arn: ${self:custom.snsTopicArn} topicName: ${self:custom.snsTopic}" Build deployed with out any error but when I check the lambda details in AWS console the is no event bind to this lambda and when I check details of the SNS Topic, subscription list is empty

Comment: As I mentioned earlier the only way I could get it working is hardcording arn to the sns value "events: -sns: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxID:project-backend-name-topicStage}"

Comment: you should use the arn like mentioned here https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/sns#using-a-pre-existing-topic

Comment: Tried "arn: !Ref SNSTopic". Build deployed without any error. But SNS topic is not found in the event section of the lambda details in AWS console. SNSTopic subscription is also empty

Comment: could you share how are you setting the events on you function?
have tried with a fresh project with what you provided and it configured the sns
included the full serverless.yml that I tested

Comment: @antajopaulson did you finf how to add in a function a sns referente that is on resource? My serverless deployed bu did not make the signature on the topic and lambda. thanks.

Comment: @dege Here is my code sample 
  `SampleFunction:
    handler: src/lambdaHandler
    events:
      - sns: ${self:custom.mySnsTopic}`. 
   You refer more here https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/events/

Comment: @2Fast4YouBR I referred my SNS topic under my functions events list. `SampleFunction:     handler: src/lambdaHandler     events:       - sns: ${self:custom.mySnsTopic}`